# jQuery autoNumeric plugin replace euro sign with question mark

Tags: jquery, encoding

i'm using [autoNumeric](http://www.decorplanit.com/plugin/), a jQuery plugin that automatically formats currency.
Everything works fine, but the euro sign (€) is replaced by question mark (�).

I have already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6810587/euro-sign-not-showing-on-site) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8084359/xmlhttprequest-displays-eurosign-as-questionmark), but it not seems to be an encoding problem couse I'm using the following meta tags on the page:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Also replacing exotic characters by their html friendly such as `&euro;` code in the autoNumeric options, did not solve the problem, it simply show `&euro; 123,00` in the field input

```
$('#import').autoNumeric('init', {
        aSep: '.',
        aDec: ',',
        vMin: '-999999999.99',
        vMax: '999999999.99',
        aSign: '€' // also tried with '&euro;'
    });
```

If I replace euro sign with dollar sign (`aSign: '$'`) it works fine!

Thanks in advance

Comment: What about other characters like ☃ or ♠︎? Also is your JavaScript served up as UTF-8? This might be an issue if you pull it in from a separate file.

Comment: `aSign : '\u20AC'` should work. Try it.

Comment: I'll try it tomorrow, thanks both for replies

Comment: Glad to help, Adding an answer below so it could help future users with similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem might be due to character encoding mismatch ([Refer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1372544/3639582))

Use unicode value for `€`.

```
aSign : '\u20AC'
```

---

```
$('#import').autoNumeric('init', {
    aSep: '.',
    aDec: ',',
    vMin: '-999999999.99',
    vMax: '999999999.99',
    aSign : '\u20AC'
});
```